# how to set unique id to each row in a column on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to set some column of each row in a table to some unique value e.g.

```
update mytable set myCol=rownum()
```

using SQL (not T/SQL) on SQL Server 2000.
I can't touch the schema but I do have a spare column or two.

Comment: since you can't touch the schema, are you doing this in code? if so, what language?

Comment: I want to execute DML SQL against the table.  I can't add identifier column or anything like that.

Comment: Is there an existing unique column? What types are the "spare" columns?

Comment: no existing unique column.  Available columns are numeric and varchar2.  Thanks for fixing the tag.

Comment: What restrictions do you have, apart from identity columns? _Why_ do you have these restrictions? Give us some guidance, and we will be able to help you better.

Comment: My understanding is that DML (Data Manipulation Language) is something like update mytable set myCol=rownum().  That's the sort of thing I want to do.  Sorry if I get the terminology wrong.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Sorry about that - thought I saw DDL...

Comment: Is it possible to order your rows by a set of fields?

Comment: DML SQL in SQL Server 2000 **IS** T-SQL (Transact-SQL).... why do you explicitly exclude this in your post??

Comment: Could you create a helper table to aid in this endeavour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided that you have a primary key, you can generate a unique value by counting rows.  For example (replace `#t` with your table's name):

```
update  t
set     t.col1 = (select COUNT(*) from #t t2 where t.pk >= t2.pk)
from    #t t
```

If you have a `varchar(36)` or larger, you can generate GUID's, which are guaranteed to be unique:

```
update  #t
set     col1 = NEWID()
```

If you have neither, you can use a variable.  This technique is frowned upon because it's not set based, but it works pretty well:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1

update  #t
set     col1 = @i
,       @i = @i + 1
```